# how to develop a custom connector in SailPoint

Tags: sailpoint

I am novices to the field of Identity and Access management. 
Till now I know, Sail point has provided the some direct connectors to integrate the known systems like  LDAP, HR systems, OIM, Databases.. 
And sailpoint also provided the support for disconnected applications with the use of Custom connectors.
Here, My question is how to develop a custom connector..?
I do not have jar file provided by sailpoint which contain "AbstractConnector" class.
So that I can write my own class and develop..?
I also so not understand, what to do with that class?(if i have a jar) 
How sailpoint will refer to that class..
Do we need to deploy that class to somewhere...

Here I am expecting the complete flow to develop and deploy the custom connector..
If anyone is working please help..

Answer (score 5):

If you unzip your `identityiq.war`, you'll find a JAR file called `WEB-INF/lib/connector-bundle.jar`. This is the JAR where you'll find AbstractConnector. Once you've written your connector code, you will need to compile it and bundle it into a JAR file, which you will place into `WEB-INF/lib`.

Finally, you will need to update the ConnectorRegistry object (under Configuration on the debug screen) to reference the new class, which will make it available as an Application type. If it has custom connection parameters (as most do), you will also need an xhtml page that will be embedded into the Sailpoint UI to prompt the user configuring the Application.

If you have Compass access, they have a whitepaper called [Custom Connectors](https://community.sailpoint.com/docs/DOC-4793) that you will find helpful.

All that said, I encourage you to try to find a way to use an out-of-box connector if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times it will be better if you use the DelimitedFile connector, you can import a CSV of identity data, and make it work within Sailpoint's workflow.  You will be able to map fields, correlate accounts and create multi-valued group memberships rapidly.  Of course, this means that Sailpoint will not be connected directly to the application, and you will have to develop a workflow to extract the identities and upload them.  But at least, you can integrate without going the Custom Connector way.